# How are Heroku worker and clock processes priced?

Tags: python, heroku

I have a python script that I want to run every couple of minutes on Heroku. I'm planning to use [a clock process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python) to [queue the job](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq).

I can't work out what this would cost. Would this amount to having two dynos running constantly (`clock` and `worker`)? Or would usage only count the small amount of time when the clock process runs, and when the (quick) tasks are run from the queue?

In the latter case I expect it would come within the free 750 dyno hours / month usage, but I'm not sure if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are running constantly so therefore billed for the number of hours in the month. Your 750 free dyno hours would cover part of the cost though.

The Heroku scheduler addon will let you run tasks at various intervals which will only be billed whilst the task is executing.

Comment: Thanks John. I suspected as much, but couldn't find clarification that they both ran constantly. I'm using the Scheduler addon at the moment, but ideally I want something that will run more frequently than every 10 minutes.